# How to add properties file to classpath in Grails

Tags: grails

What does it mean when it says to add a file to the classpath? Something like this:

```
// The configuration file we created. It must be in the classpath.
outEncryptionProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENC_PROP_FILE, "client_encryption.properties");
```

I use GGTS and I have other files other than properties file that I need to add to my project's classpath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classpath is a collection of jars and directories that are used to resolve classes and resources. In practice for files like this putting them in the classpath means that you should put it in a directory that's included in the classpath, or a directory whose contents are copied to a classpath folder during compilation.

In Grails you can put non-source files in `grails-app/conf`, `src/java`, or `src/groovy` and they'll be copied into the classpath.